# Крымский – значит для Крыма. Верна ли пунктуация после слова «значит»?

Tags: пунктуация

Крымский – значит для Крыма. Верна ли пунктуация после слова «значит», а именно отсутствие запятой.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможны варианты с разными смысловыми оттенками:

1. ***Крымский – значит для Крыма.***   В функции связки: Крымский –  **это  значит** для Крыма.
2. ***Крымский – значит, для Крыма***.  В функции вводного слова: Крымский – **следовательно**, для Крыма.